# Laravel Composer laravel new command

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to set laravel new command, but it is showing error like that.

I have laravel file inside `/.composer/vendor/bin`

[image]

[image]

how can I solve this

Comment: What is the command you fired?

Comment: Can you share your error message in readable form? Usually, that is text that can be shared best as text :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create new Laravel project you can use command:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-new-project`

instead of installer.

On your screenshot it says that Laravel Installer is already installed so it has nothing to install or update. So you might want to run command `laravel new blog` in fresh new empty directory and it may be working already.

If you're trying to create new console command in Laravel project and you want this command to be accessible from console and it could be something like `php artisan my-command:run` you can do the following below.

To do so you might want to generate new command executing this Laravel command from root directory of your project:

`php artisan make:command MyCommand`

This command above is going to create new class under `App\Console\Commands` called `MyCommand` and it will be ready for customizing.
You can change property `protected $signature = 'my-command:run';` and then when you run `php artisan my-command:run` from root directory of the project this command is going to run `App\Console\Commands\MyCommand::handle()` method and everything inside it will be executed. So you can edit the method and achieve there what you want and the command will be ready.

For details you can refer to this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan